# Joining on the latest value before a given a date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table of prices:

```
ticker | date       | price
 X     | 2018-06-30 | 100
 X     | 2018-03-31 | 200
 X     | 2018-01-30 | 300
```

and another table of other data keyed on ticker and date:

```
ticker | date       | other data
 X     | 2018-04-01 | 12
 X     | 2018-03-31 | 25
 X     | 2018-03-30 | 65
```

I want to join the second table with the latest price for that ticker before or equal to that date, like:

```
ticker | date       | other data | price
 X     | 2018-04-01 | 12         | 200
 X     | 2018-03-31 | 25         | 200
 X     | 2018-03-30 | 65         | 300
```

I am using Redshift, but any SQL dialect would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *correlated* `subquery` :

```
select t.*, (select p.price
             from price p
             where p.ticker = t.ticker and p.date <= t.date
             order by p.date desc
             limit 1
            ) as price
from table t;
```

**EDIT** : If you want `date` also then you can do `JOIN` :

```
select t.*, p.price, p.date
from table t inner join
     price p
     on p.ticker = t.ticker
where p.date = (select p1.date
                from price p1
                where p1.ticker = t.ticker and p1.date <= t.date
                order by p1.date desc 
                limit 1
               );
```

Comment: `where p.ticker = t.ticker and p.date <= min(t.date)` is probably better (without the order by and limit)

Comment: Is there a way to get more than one column from the subquery? I would also like to know the date of the price that is used. @Yogesh Sharma

Comment: @user1742188. . . You need `JOIN`.

Comment: @user1742188 . . . Does the correlated subquery actually perform well in Redshift on a largish amount of data?